# how can i make a component re render in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, rendering

so i'm creating my first fullstack website and once a user signs in it gets stored in the localStorage and i want to display the name of the user in my header once he is logged in but my header is not re rendering so nothing happens : this is the header before logging in
[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qps1.png)

and this is how i want it to Be after signing in :
[header after logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOJBF.png) this is my Layout code:

```
import "../assets/sass/categoriesbar.scss";
import Header from "./Header/Header";

const Layout = (props) => {

return ( 
    <>
        <Header/>
        <main>
           { props.children}
        </main>
        
    </>
 );
}

export default Layout;
```

and this is the toolBar in my Header :

```
const ToolBar = () => {
const history = useHistory();
let currentUser= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info"));

const logoutHandler = () => {
 localStorage.clear("user-info");

 history.push("/login");
 };
 return (
   <>
   <div className={classes.NavigationBar}>
   <h1>
     <Link to="/">Pharmashop</Link>
   </h1>
   <NavLinks logout={logoutHandler}/>
   {localStorage.getItem("user-info")? 
     <h5>Welcome {currentUser.name} !</h5>
    : 
    <RegisterButton />
   }
  </div>
  </>
 


);

};

export default ToolBar;
```

please help me it's frustrating

PS: this is my first stackoverflow question sorry if it's unorganized and unclear and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: There's nothing quite like referring to the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hazem, welcome to Stack Overflow.

In react, if you want the component to re-render when some data changes, that info must be in the component state. In your code the current user is a const, not bind to the component's state. This is how it could auto re-render when the user logs in:

```
const ToolBar = () => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user-info")));

    const logoutHandler = () => {
     localStorage.clear("user-info");

     history.push("/login");
     };
     return (
       <>
       <div className={classes.NavigationBar}>
           <h1>
             <Link to="/">Pharmashop</Link>
           </h1>
           <NavLinks logout={logoutHandler}/>
           {currentUser? 
             <h5>Welcome {currentUser.name} !</h5>
            : 
            <RegisterButton />
           }
          </div>
      </>
    );
};

export default ToolBar;
```

See more about state in the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: that didn't quite work but i solved the problem using the context api (kind of ugly solution) but at least it works, thanks for the help anyway :)